# Send multiple headers or multiple submitting for the form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When the user inserts two numbers (from-to), I want to send (((full path))) for each number.
how would I accomplish this? Is there a way in PHP, javascript or any other language. Would I send many headers or multiple submissions for the form?

P.S:
The (go.php) page that receive and process each number individually.. I can't put hands on it to make changes, I only must send individual numbers to it because that's how the other page is coded.

This what i've tried:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first">
<input type="text" name="second">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
$f=$_POST['first'];
$s=$_POST['second'];
for($i=$f; $i<=$s; $i++){
header('location:go.php?f='.$i);
}
?>
```

Comment: whats the error it shows?

Comment: it only sends the last header with the last number

Comment: actually PHP header function does not allow send more than one header function.What it happens is, it overrides with the latest value. So i think thats the reason you are redirecting to the last number.

Comment: yes i know that , is there a way to send full path for each :(

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? It doesn't make sense to redirect people hundreds of times.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?  What are you attempting to do?

Comment: `header("location:go.php?f=$f&s=$s)"` ?

Comment: there is other web page that receive and process each number individually.. i cant put hands on it to make changes, i only must send individual numbers to it because thats how the other page coded

Comment: Then what you need to use is cURL instead.

Comment: and how to manage that cURL .. can you tell me plz

Answer (score 0):

you can not send header twice you can do this like below

```
<?php
$f=$_POST['first'];
$s=$_POST['second'];
header('location:go.php?first='.$i.'&second='.$s);
?>
```

**go.php**

you can catch these two variables using get method

```
<?php
    $first=$_GET['first'];
    $second=$_GET['second'];

    //rest of the code
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use javascript to submit so many times:

```
// supposing you have jQuery
for (var i = Number($(':input[name=first]').val()),
       end = Number($(':input[name=second]').val()); 
         i <= end; i++) {
    $.get('go.php', { f: i }, function (response){ 
         // do something with response
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via simple single script. You can do it via multithreading or  curl. I am giving you example of curl:

one.php

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first">
<input type="text" name="second">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
$f=$_POST['first'];
$s=$_POST['second'];
for($i=$f; $i<=$s; $i++){
  //write curl code to execute two.php with url : http:// yoursite.com/two.php?f=$i
}
?>
```

two.php

```
<?php
    header('location:go.php?f='.$_REQEST['f']);
?>
```

Hope this explanation help you. Best of Luck.